# How to use puppeteer on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, puppeteer

I am trying to use puppeteer on heroku to do web automatisation.

The script gets activated by a webpage click. I am using a "stealth" version of puppeteer to make it undetected.

I installed this: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack.

As soon as I start the script it throws the error

```
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105176+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed.
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105178+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:183:56
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105180+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105181+00:00 app[web.1]:     at CDPSession.send (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:182:12)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105183+00:00 app[web.1]:     at navigate (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:118:39)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105184+00:00 app[web.1]:     at FrameManager.navigateFrame (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:95:7)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105185+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Frame.goto (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:406:37)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105186+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Frame.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105187+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Page.goto (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:675:49)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105188+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Page.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105189+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.addxp (/app/bot/bot.js:37:20)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105190+00:00 app[web.1]:   -- ASYNC --
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105192+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Frame.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105193+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Page.goto (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:675:49)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105194+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Page.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105195+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.addxp (/app/bot/bot.js:37:20)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105196+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.start (/app/bot/start.js:10:11)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105197+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/server.js:123:23
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105198+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105247+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105340+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105343+00:00 app[web.1]:     at CDPSession.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/LifecycleWatcher.js:46:107)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105344+00:00 app[web.1]:     at CDPSession.emit (events.js:215:7)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105345+00:00 app[web.1]:     at CDPSession._onClosed (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:215:10)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105347+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection._onClose (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:138:15)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105348+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.dispose (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:144:10)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105350+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Browser.disconnect (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Browser.js:260:22)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105351+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Browser.close (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Browser.js:256:10)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105352+00:00 app[web.1]:     at async Object.close (/app/bot/bot.js:45:5)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105354+00:00 app[web.1]:   -- ASYNC --
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105355+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Frame.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105356+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Page.goto (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:675:49)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105358+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Page.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105359+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.login (/app/bot/bot.js:20:20)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105361+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.start (/app/bot/start.js:8:11)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105362+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/server.js:123:23
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105363+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
2019-12-11T18:42:41.105367+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 5)
```

. Anything I need to install? Do i need to mark the script as a worker in Procfile?